# R Populate a vector by matching names to df column values

Tags: r

I have a named vector filled with zeros

```
toy1<- rep(0, length(37:45))
names(toy1) <- 37:45
```

I want to populate the vector with count data from a dataframe

```
size    count
37      1.181
38      0.421
39      0.054
40      0.005
41      0.031
42      0.582
45      0.024
```

I need help finding a way to match the value for size to the vector name and then input the corresponding count value into that vector position

Comment: `count` is a numeric column in the dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be as simple as:

```
toy1[ as.character(dat$size) ] <- dat$count
toy1

#   37    38    39    40    41    42    43    44    45 
#1.181 0.421 0.054 0.005 0.031 0.582 0.000 0.000 0.024
```

R's indexing for assignments can have character values. If you had just tried to index with the raw column:

```
toy1[ dat$size ] <- dat$count
```

You would have gotten (as did I initially):

```
> toy1
   37    38    39    40    41    42    43    44    45                                                             
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 

   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 1.181 0.421 

0.054 0.005 0.031 0.582    NA    NA 0.024
```

That occurred because numeric indexing occurred and there was default extension of the length of the vector to accommodate the numbers up to 45.

With a version of the dataframe that had a number that was not in the range 37:45, I did get a warning from using `match` with a nomatch of 0, but I also got the expected results:

```
toy1[ match( as.character( dat$size), names(toy1) , nomatch=0) ] <- dat$count
#------------
Warning message:
In toy1[match(as.character(dat$size), names(toy1), nomatch = 0)] <- dat$count :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> toy1
   37    38    39    40    41    42    43    44    45 
1.181 0.421 0.054 0.005 0.031 0.582 0.000 0.000 0.000
```

The `match` function is at the core of the `merge` function but this application would be much faster than a `merge` of dataframes

Comment: This works! Thanks for taking the time to explain why `as.character` is necessary

Comment: One watchout - if `df$size` has a value that is not in `toy1` then `toy1` will have new elements added to it. This doesn't just update `toy1`

Comment: Yes. I started out by coding with `match` and if that feature were needed by the OP, I still might go back to it.

Comment: This is actually a concern. I only want to input data for the range of sizes  named in `toy1` without adding extra sizes

Answer (score 2):

Lets say your data frame is *df*, then you can  just update the records in *toy1* for records available in your data frame:

```
toy1[as.character(df$size)]    <- df$count
```

Edit: To check for a match *m* before updating the records. *m* are the matched indices in *size* column of *df*:

```
m <- match(names(toy1), as.character(df$size))
```

Then, for the indices in *toy1* which have a match, it can be updated as below:

```
toy1[which(!is.na(m))]    <- df$count[m[!is.na(m)]]
```

PS: Efficient way would be to define *toy1* as a data frame and perform an outer join  by *size* column.

Comment: If there is a value in `df$size` that is not in `toy1` then this will add new elements to `toy1`

Comment: @Mark. Joins would be an efficient way to handle it. I added a match before updating 'toy1' for this case.

Comment: I'd make sure to test that last one when the 'size' values are not ordered. The OP didn't give a very good example for testing. It missed several edge-cases.

Comment: @42- I agree with not a good example. I tested, ordering is being taken care by the match 'm' which is used to create logic vectors afterwards.

Comment: I was worried that the `!is.na(.)` would remove the ordering information on the left side of the last assignment, ... but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's get the data loaded in.

```
toy1<- rep(0, length(37:45))
names(toy1) <- 37:45
df = read.table(text="37      1.181
38      0.421
39      0.054
40      0.005
41      0.031
42      0.582
45      0.024")
names(df) = c("size","count")
```

Now, I present a really ugly solution.  We only update `toy1` where the name of `toy1` appears in `df$size`. We return `df$count` by obtaining the index of the match in `df`. I use `sapply` to get a vector of the index back. On both sizes we only look for places where `names(toy1)` appear in `df$size`.

```
toy1[names(toy1) %in% df$size] = df$count[sapply(names(toy1)[names(toy1) %in% df$size],function(x){which(x == df$size)})]
```

But, this isn't very elegant. Instead, you could turn `toy1` into a data.frame.

```
toydf = data.frame(toy1 = toy1,name = names(toy1),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now, we can use `merge` to get the values.

```
updated = merge(toydf,df,by.x = "name",by.y="size",all.x=T)
```

This returns a 3 column data.frame. You can then extract the `count` column from this, replace NA with 0 and you're done.

```
updated$count[is.na(updated$count)] = 0
updated$count
#> [1] 1.181 0.421 0.054 0.005 0.031 0.582 0.000 0.000 0.024
```